# MySQL Retrieve Password field from database using email field

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new using php and I'm making a login window for my page where I want to compare if the email and password from the inputs are the same to those in the database; I already have the comparison for the email but I don't know how to retrieve the exact password for that email and compare it with the password input to know if it's the same. 
This is what I have for my php:

```
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$query = mysql_query( "SELECT email FROM Register WHERE email = '$email'");
$query2 = mysql_query( "SELECT password FROM Register WHERE email = '$email', password = '$password'");



    if(!$email)
    {
        if (!$password)
        {
            echo '
            <script>
            alert("Email and password are required.");
            window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            echo '
            <script>
            alert("Email Required.");
            window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
            exit;
        }           
    }

    if (!$password)
    {
        echo '
        <script>
        alert("Password required.");
        window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';
        exit;
    }

    else
    {


        if(!mysql_num_rows($query))
        {
            echo '
            <script>
            alert("The email is not the same or does not exist");
            window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
            exit;
        }

        if($query2==$password)
        {
            echo '
            <script>
            alert("Succesful Login");
            window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
            exit;
        }

        else
        {
            echo '
            <script>
            alert("Password is not the same, please verify.");
            window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
            exit;

        }




    }
```

By the way, thank you for your help

Comment: is your password encrypted ??

Comment: No no, I have it simple with POST and with type "password" in the HTML

Comment: then just put and AND instead of comma after email = $email and password=$password like this in the 2nd query

Comment: you are welcome, and dont verify an answer and then unverify it, it feels bad. both the answers given are correct. so you should judge the verified ans according to the time bro. anyways cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleas try this

```
 mysqli_query( "SELECT * FROM Register WHERE email = '$email' and password ='$password'");

if(mysql_num_rows($query))
{
            echo '
            <script>
            alert("Succesful Login");
            window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
            exit;
 }
else
{
            echo '
            <script>
            alert("The email is not the same or does not exist");
            window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
            exit;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change query like below

`SELECT password FROM Register WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'`

Also use mysqli* because mysql* is deprecated and completly removed in Php 7

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Comment: Thanks, also needed to use mysql_num_rows($query2) for the verification in the if

Answer (score 1):

1. you are using "," instead of "AND". use and it shall solve
2. after executing 2nd query your data will be in $query. you have use

   ```
   $data=mysql_fetch_array($query);
   $data['password'];// there contains password
   so you code this
   if($query2==$password)
           {
               echo '
               <script>
               alert("Succesful Login");
               window.history.go(-1);
               </script>';
               exit;
           }
   will be changed to
   if($data['password']==$password)
           {
               echo '
               <script>
               alert("Succesful Login");
               window.history.go(-1);
               </script>';
               exit;
           }
   ```

hope you get answer.